# Prevent zooming Google Map on iOS with VoiceOver

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Using the Google Maps SDK for iOS you can disabling zooming the map by calling `setAllGesturesEnabled:NO` which will turn off all the gestures including the pinch to zoom gesture. But if you turn on accessibility support for the map via `accessibilityElementsHidden = NO`, VoiceOver users are still able to zoom by tapping the map then swiping up/down with one finger. How do you completely disable zooming for all users?

I would like to maintain full accessibility support and simply disable zooming, panning, and rotation.

Comment: Not sure, but how about adding an observer wich indeed trace the changes in zoom factor and reset at initial scale/factor?  Another solution comes in mind: observe voiceover action and disable all touches in map while it is in use?

Comment: I want full to preserve full accessibility support for the map, just no ability to change the zoom level (or rotate the map or change the angle).

Comment: Set the delegate. If you are on Google Sdk, mapView_.settings.zoomGestures = NO; also for tiltGestures.

Comment: That does't disable the zoom functionality when using VoiceOver unfortunately - it only disables the gesture non-VoiceOver users use.